# Renaming multiple files using sed or awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a DVR recorder that sends files to my linux ftp server with a specific name, but I need to change to another name format so they can be used on the older software.
The original files came with this format:

```
DVR_ch1_principal_20150427094000_20150427100000.dav

DVR=Device Name
ch1=channel#

principal=stream type

20150427094000=starting date in year,month,day,hour,minute,second format

20150427100000=end date in year,month,day,hour,minute,second format
```

I need to modify all files in a folder to this format:

```
ch1_09.04.00-10.00.00.dav

ch1=channel#

09.04.00=starting time in hh.mm.ss

10.00.00=end time in hh.mm.ss
```

I know it can be done using sed or ark, but it's beyond my knowledge.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @JID I often ask this myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWK&bash Version:

```
for FNAME in $(ls -1 *.dav)
  do
    channel=$(echo ${FNAME} | awk -F _ '{print $2}')
    starttime=$(echo ${FNAME} | awk -F _ '{print $4}')
    endtime=$(echo ${FNAME} | awk -F _ '{print $5}')
    #
    echo ${channel}
    #
    STARTH=${starttime:8:2}
    STARTM=${starttime:10:2}
    STARTS=${starttime:12:2}
    ENDH=${endtime:8:2}
    ENDM=${endtime:10:2}
    ENDS=${endtime:12:2}
    #
    echo ${channel}"_"${STARTH}"."${STARTM}"."${STARTS}"-"${ENDH}"."${ENDM}"."${ENDS}".dav"
    mv -f ${FNAME} ${channel}"_"${STARTH}"."${STARTM}"."${STARTS}"-"${ENDH}"."${ENDM}"."${ENDS}".dav"
  done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '
# ch1_09.04.00-10.00.00.dav
/^DVR_ch/ {
   s/.*\(ch[0-9]\{1,\}\).*\([0-9]\{6\}\)_.*\(([0-9]\{6\}.\{4\}\)$/\1-\2-\3
   s/\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)/\.\2.\3\
/g
   p
   }
#ch1=channel
/=channel/ p

#=starting date 
/=starting date/ s/[0-9]*\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)=.*/\
\1.\2.\3=starting time in hh.mm.ss/p

#=end date 
/=starting date/ s/[0-9]*\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)=.*/\
\1.\2.\3=end time in hh.mm.ss/p
' YourFile
```

Self commented (posix version so '--posix' in linux GNU sed)
It's mainly reformating info from line